# What are design ideas or elements that fit between Winter and Spring?

Tags: posters

I have to change a poster that is designed to be seasonal. The poster (below) is too "Xmas" for the office and it can't be a Spring design as we are located in Illinois. I think the wreath part & snowman in the poster could give off the Xmas feel but what are design ideas or elements that fit between Winter and Spring?

My thought was that the poster could be too gloomy and dark.

[image: poster]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the elements that would remind someone of Christmas.  Clearly a wreath and acorns (usually found on a tree) would give that impression.

I would personally leave the snowmen but look for colors that are not red or green to help relieve the impression of the Christmas season.

If you are looking for ideas do research for your area that would help influence the idea of a season change so look at history/season patterns for your area.  Elements that would encourage or draw the impression/idea of season change for everyone in your office should be your goal.